# IP forwarding service? VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, hosting

We have a need to connect two machines to one another, where "connect" means multiple (but known) TCP channels and UDP streams. We don't have very much control over how they each connect to the Internet - one end uses a proprietary satellite link, the other relies on customers providing their own Internet connection of some kind. Clearly in order to do this a "mirror" is needed whose address is fixed and known to both ends, to which they each send packets and have them forwarded on to the other.

This has been done in the past using an EC2 instance in the middle, but that puts on us the responsibility to handle scaling, failover, OS patching, and so on - ops tasks which are not our core business and which we're not staffed to do long-term. It seems to me that the correct approach is to outsource all that by buying in a "forwarding service" instead. Assuming such things exist; I'm actually mildly surprised that the ever-growing AWS catalogue doesn't seem to include anything suitable.

Can anyone suggest a suitable service? Reliability is a higher priority than price, I expect networking costs to be dominated by satellite data anyway. Bonus points for a UK presence since this will give certain customers warm fuzzies.

I haven't worked out all the details yet, but I guess the "customer connection" client is going to need to be coming in over a VPN (or some other kind of authentication?). Standard VPN technologies preferred, but at minimum any proprietary client must have a decent Linux version. The Internet connection to and from the satellite service I believe operates on a system of whitelisting IPs.

Any other thoughts on this situation are welcome, I'm at a pretty early stage of designing the solution. I know my way round a network but it's not my core skill.

Comment: Dynamic DNS with a short TTL? Do the TCP/UDP streams need to be real-time, or could you use something like https://aws.amazon.com/iot/?

Comment: Certainly need to be real-time, not stored and forwarded. I don't think dynamic DNS would be sufficient because one end (and probably both) is behind NAT and firewalls that we don't control.

Comment: I've now spoken to my colleague who set up a similar system before, and what they put on EC2 was a CentOS instance running StrongSwan IPsec tunnels, initiated by the client on both sides.

I guess I have a clearer idea of what to search for now, this question might be redundant.